# If certain radio buttons checked, display div else display different div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

:) So I'm trying to create a user questionaire type form, it doesnt have to send to anyone just display a div once certain radio buttons are checked and if them certain radio buttons arent checked then display a different div, but also when the webpage opens/refreshes none of the div's I want to display to be displayed (if that makes sense?). I found some code on here to try but it didnt work for me, I'm a noob with JS & Jquery but was hoping anyone could shed some light on my problem. please find my code below.

Jquery?

```
if($('input[value=yes1]:checked,
 input[value=yes2]:checked, 
 input[value=yes3]:checked,
 input[value=yes4]:checked').length == 4){

$("#correct").show();

 }else{

$("#correct").hide();
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="left">

    <div class="right answer">
        <div class="leftradio">
            <input type="radio" id="yes1" value="yes1" name="iCheck1">
            <label>Yes</label>
            </input>
        </div>

        <div class="rightradio">
            <input type="radio" id="no1" name="iCheck1">
            <label>No</label>
            </input>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="right">

    <div class="right answer">
        <div class="leftradio">
            <input type="radio" id="yes2" value="yes2" name="iCheck2">
            <label>Yes</label>
            </input>
        </div>

        <div class="rightradio">
            <input type="radio" id="no2" name="iCheck2">
            <label>No</label>
            </input>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Yes
                
            

            
                
                No
                
            

        

    
    

        
            
                
                Yes
                
            

            
                
                No

CSS

```
#correct{width:100%; height:50px; background:green; display:none;}
#incorrect{width:100%; height:50px; background:red; display:none;}
```

Comment: First, yes; that's jQuery. Further, might I suggest using some punctuation and breaking up your sentences a little, which might let us understand your question a little more clearly. This is a JavaScript/jQuery question: that it hasn't been answered (even with guesses) after fourteen minutes (as I write this comment), suggests that nobody knows what you want. Please: assume we know nothing about your code, or your intent. Explain, clearly, what you want to happen (checking which radio should have what effect(s)?) and what went wrong with your own attempts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. I had to change the number of "correct" answers to two because that's all the html you have.

JS:

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    if($('input[value=yes1]:checked, input[value=yes2]:checked').length === 2){
       $("#correct").show();
    }else{
       $("#correct").hide();
    }
});
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akj84vrq/12/

Comment: This was exactly what i wanted thanks alot! Apologies to all with my bad punctuation, i was in a rush :|

Comment: Right, slight problem :| the code works on JSfiddle but when i insert into a live html/php file it doesnt work?

Comment: Can you check to see in their are any JS errors? Try adding `alert` or `console.log` in you code to see if it's even getting evaluated... If you don't see the alert on console.log printing, then you know that your JS isn't getting properly evaluated or maybe it's not even running at all. http://jsfiddle.net/akj84vrq/14/

Comment: in the JSfiddle window, an alert box appears on screen, however, putting in on a live page it doesnt work? i've just checked to see if JS is enabled and it is! I'm comfused now! :|

Comment: Just found the issue, was missing some of the code :S damn computer playing up and not copying all of the code, think thats why only two of the answer boxes was pasted on my original post :|

Answer (score 0):

A little something like this would probably get you what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/uu512erm/

Listen for change event on the radio inputs by `$('input:radio').change(function(){}`
and then just add the logic inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this can be accomplished via CSS.

Now, you are checking against some values/elements that don't exist in your code (ie `input[value=yes3]:checked`, you don't have input with that value, check it for yourself).

I don't understand what exactly you want to accomplish, but I will still try to help and since you're new let's keep it very basic:

```
if ($('input[value=yes1]').is(':checked') && $('input[value=yes2]').is(':checked')) {
  // this will fire only if input with values yes1 and yes2 is checked
  $('div_to_show').show(); // put your own selectors here
  $('div_to_hide').hide(); // put your own selectors here
} 

if ($('input[value=no1]').is(':checked') && $('input[value=no2]').is(':checked')) {
  // this will fire only if input with values no1 and no2 is checked
  $('some_other_div_to_show').show(); // put your own selectors here
  $('some_other_div_to_hide').hide(); // put your own selectors here
}

if ($('input[value=yes1]').is(':checked') && $('input[value=no1]').is(':checked')) {
  # this will fire only if both input with values yes1 and no1 is checked
  $('some_other_div_to_show').show(); # put your own selectors here
  $('some_other_div_to_hide').hide(); # put your own selectors here
} 

# and so on... just type in your conditions and that's it.
```

If you need some other cases, just add them using this pattern or construct one complex else if statement with all your scenarios.